# ssis 2010 Dynamic variable file name

Tags: ssis

using SSIS and excel 2013

I have a foreach loop container , that loops the excel file and transforms the data as the file name is dynamic

after that I want to move the file using a file system task.

However the file name is dynamic

I want to store the file location and file name in a variable , but how do you do this is the file name is different each time

how is this achievable please

please help

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with a filesystem task.

Make sure to use rename file not move file as the Operation. (for some reason move does not work with variables!)

Then you just use the filename that you get from your foreach variable set as the source variable. (isSourcePathVariable=True)
You might need to a variable that you set within the loop to store your destination...